# Who ran Ten-Forward before Guinan?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

At the beginning of Season 2 (TNG), we are first introduced to Guinan as being in charge of Ten-Forward, but I don't recall who the original person who ran Ten-Forward was in the series.

I seem to recall seeing Ten-Forward before this, and we know there was an exchange of crewmen at the beginning of S2, so who ran Ten-Forward before Guinan did?

Comment: Ten Forward did not make an appearance in Season 1. Its first appearance was in Season 2 Episode 1: The Child. This is not to say it did not "exist" in-universe, merely that any memory of seeing it prior to Season 2 is incorrect

Comment: A Mr Eleven Backward founded and named the bar, but somehow he never seemed able to make any progress with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think anyone was in charge of Ten Forward prior to Guinan aside from the civilian wait staff. (BTW the episode "All Good Things..." proved that Ten Forward was an unseen part of the Enterprise prior to Season 2: "Ten Forward hosted a reception shortly following Captain Picard's arrival in 2364. Counselor Deanna Troi introduced the captain to the senior officers at that time. (TNG: "All Good Things...")"  - from the Memory Alpha entry on Ten Forward.)

According to Memory Alpha Guinan was invited on board the Enterprise in 2365 as host of Ten Forward at Captain Picard's request and afforded a small office, which suggests a special position was created for Guinan rather than her taking on the duties of an existing crew member.

Comment: Does Memory Alpha have a source for that?

Comment: *BTW the episode "All Good Things..." proved that Ten Forward was an unseen part of the Enterprise prior to Season 2.* How so? Out of interest, you should expand that a bit more, if you mention it.

Comment: I've added more source details about Ten Forward in "All Good Things...". I didn't find specific sources about when Picard requested Guinan come aboard.

Comment: When Picard realised Riker was on the verge of becoming [addicted to holographic prostitutes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/11001001_(episode)), he figured Ten Forward needed some help.